# fMeasure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'label' - print_performance_metrics(predictions)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import BinaryClassificationEvaluator
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import BinaryClassificationMetrics, MulticlassMetrics

def print_performance_metrics(predictions):
  # Evaluate model
  evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator(rawPredictionCol="rawPrediction")
  auc = evaluator.evaluate(predictions, {evaluator.metricName: "areaUnderROC"})
  aupr = evaluator.evaluate(predictions, {evaluator.metricName: "areaUnderPR"})
  print("auc = {}".format(auc))
  print("aupr = {}".format(aupr))

  # get rdd of predictions and labels for mllib eval metrics
  predictionAndLabels = predictions.select("prediction","label").rdd

  # Instantiate metrics objects
  binary_metrics = BinaryClassificationMetrics(predictionAndLabels)
  multi_metrics = MulticlassMetrics(predictionAndLabels)

  # Area under precision-recall curve
  print("Area under PR = {}".format(binary_metrics.areaUnderPR))
  # Area under ROC curve
  print("Area under ROC = {}".format(binary_metrics.areaUnderROC))
  # Accuracy
  print("Accuracy = {}".format(multi_metrics.accuracy))
  # Confusion Matrix
  print(multi_metrics.confusionMatrix())
  

  ### Question F1, Precision Score ###
  
  # F1
  print("F1 = {}".format(multi_metrics.fMeasure()))
  # Precision
 # print("Precision = {}".format(multi_metrics.precision()))
  # Recall
 # print("Recall = {}".format(multi_metrics.recall()))
  # FPR
 # print("FPR = {}".format(multi_metrics.falsePositiveRate(0.0)))
  # TPR
 # print("TPR = {}".for

 mat(multi_metrics.truePositiveRate(0.0)))
```

I am working on the above function for model scores. It gave me the auc and accuracy score but it did not work for multiclassmetrics.
I am not able to get the f1 and precision scores it gives

*fMeasure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'label'*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at [the formula of F1 score](https://deepai.org/machine-learning-glossary-and-terms/f-score) you will see that it is interested in true/false labeling of one class only. So F1 score is label centric. It evaluates a kind of accuracy of models considering the true/false labeling of a certain class. The "Example" section under [the official documentation of MultiClassMetrics](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics.html#multiclassmetrics) clearly shows that you need to select one label among your existing classes to call fMeasure which is plausible when you realize that its a label centric metric as I explained.

Comment: @adem Was my comment able to help you? In case, I'll be glad if you could mark my answer as accepted. Otherwise, let me know if I can clarify further.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link, I gave the label for metrics.fMeasure(0.0, 2.0) it works but metrics.recall(2.0) does not work. the error is 
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: 2.0. Thanks

Comment: @AdemArslan Assuming by your usage of "BinaryClassificationEvaluator" before "MultiClassMetrics", your data has two labels. They are probably 0 and 1, in case "metrics.fMeasure(0.0, 2.0)" worked out. Please correct me if I am wrong. Otherwise, you could only call "recall" with the existing labels in your data. In this case they are 0 and 1.